# How rewrite TWO URLS for .HTACCESS?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

One pages of site have such adds: `domain.com/posts/name.php`
Other pages of site have such adds: `domain.com/pages/name.php`
I need to cut from these adds `posts/` and `pages/` only.

Firstly, I tried to use in .htaccess next rules:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-z0-9-]+)$ /posts/$1
RewriteRule ^([A-z0-9-]+)$ /pages/$1
```

Don't help.

Secondly, I tried to use in .htaccess such rules and conditions:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ posts/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ pages/$1 [L]
```

As result: [image of mistake 404](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E61Qz.jpg)

Also I tried to use such method:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^([A-z0-9-]+)$/(posts|pages)/([A-z0-9-]+)/$1 [NC]
RewriteRule .* domain.com/%1%3
```

Don't help....

Comment: You cannot use same case for multiple conditions you have to use some other condition for second rule.

Comment: For example? Condition with %{REQUEST_URI} ? Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

what i am understanding you need to remove the  post and pages from the url following code will help you for that.

You would need the rewrite module of Apache: mod_rewrite.

Then do something like this:

```
    RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^post/(.*)$ $1
RewriteRule ^pages/(.*)$ $1
```

Here is the official documentation of mod_rewrite: click

please test it onece I dint test the code but did same for replacing url and its work for me.

Comment: Unfortunally this code dont help in my situation.
Now I have such message: http://c2n.me/3ItekhF.jpg

Comment: I think, that all case in conditions... Itried such condition: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/(posts|pages)/(.*)` - dont help. After I tried use condition: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^([A-z0-9-]+)/(posts|pages)/([A-z0-9-]+)` - dont help too. Why? What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.

**The solution of this problem such:**

1. We enter all information about the page in the MYSQL database:
   [image of database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfiNp.jpg)
2. We generate a page from the database:
   [generation of page (php)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlnIK.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

3. Set the generated page for Human-Friendly Url:
   [file .htaccess](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ds2iS.jpg)

So everything works, and POSTS there are in their folder in the database, and PAGES in their folder.
[folder in database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzRsz.jpg)

All is clean. If you can do better somewhere, then correct me, please.